# How do I know that all files are uploaded to the server?

Tags: node.js

Am uploading files in parallel from the frontend using Promise.all([oneFile,oneFile,oneFile]) (6 files simultaneously). This is not a collection of FormData from 6 files, but specifically 6 parallel requests. There are no issues with the frontend, and upon resolving Promise.all, I understand that all files have been uploaded.

But how can I understand this on the backend? I need to perform a specific action on the server after all files have been uploaded. The simplest solution I came up with is to create 2 routes:
/upload
/done

After the user completes Promise.all, they immediately send a request to /done. But I feel like this is not a good idea because file processing will depend on the user. I would like to somehow automate it on the server... Can you help me with some advice?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so basically you should see the below code I am attaching. You should change it as per your requirements. Here I am using unique identifier to maintain it.

```
const uploadedFiles = {};

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  const { file, uniqueIdentifier } = req.body;

  if (!uploadedFiles[uniqueIdentifier]) {
    uploadedFiles[uniqueIdentifier] = [];
  }

  uploadedFiles[uniqueIdentifier].push(file);

  res.json({ success: true });
});

app.post('/done', (req, res) => {
  const { uniqueIdentifier } = req.body;

  if (uploadedFiles[uniqueIdentifier] && uploadedFiles[uniqueIdentifier].length === expectedFileCount) {

    processFiles(uploadedFiles[uniqueIdentifier]);

    delete uploadedFiles[uniqueIdentifier];

    res.json({ success: true });

  } else {

    res.json({ error: 'Not all files received yet.' });
  }
});
```

Do try and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to send all files using one request.
Attach all file in
**formData** and send request as **multipart/form-data**. If you concern about size of the files collection then you can compress them as on **zip** file and send it to the sever and then decompress it.
There is node js built in  modules like **Zlib** that you could use for this purpose.